# How to get the text not in the square bracket using regex c#?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

My string looks like below.
I want to get Completed from below string.

```
"Completed[TranslationTest]"
```

I want any text which is not in square bracket.

Comment: If you do a regex replace with nothing using the following regex, you'll be left with only what you want: `(\[.*?\])`

Comment: That worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions here, what type of chracters can be inside those brackets, but basically what you want is a something followed by positive lookahead group, like this: `\w*(?=\[[\w\W]*\])`

Comment: You could always use `[^\[\]]*(?=\[.*?\])` and just assume that any character is valid inside the brackets and assume that any character except for brackets if valid outside them.

Comment: Yep, that's cleaner than mine :)